Visit USA via land border for French citizen
Currently, I am in Canada and I would like to spend two weeks in the United States. I'll use the bus and go through the Niagara Falls border (land border).
In 2022, I filled out an I94 form and paid $6. My question: Is this type of visa still applicable?

Do you have a valid ESTA?

i-94 isn't a visa, it's a proof of your status inside the USA.

As nikhil writes in the comments, an I-94 form is not a visa but rather a proof of status in the US. Prior to October 1, 2022, visitors from Visa Waiver Program countries like France did not need to do any other paperwork to enter the US by land from Canada, but this has changed. In addition to the I-94 form filled out online or at the border, you must obtain an esta in advance of travel if you do not already have one. Per CBP's help page on the topic:

Effective October 1, 2022, all Visa Waiver Program (VWP) travelers intending to enter the United States by land will be required to obtain an approved Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA) prior to application for admission at land border ports of entry.
CBP encourages travelers to apply for a travel authorization at least 72 hours in advance of their anticipated arrival at a U.S. land port of entry.
VWP travelers intending to travel to the United States by land, sea or air must receive a travel authorization prior to application for admission to the United States and continue to pay the $6 I-94W fee provided for in 8 CFR 103.7, unless entering within the 90-day admission period.
An I-94 can be filed up to seven days prior to arrival through the CBP One mobile application for $6. The traveler can also review their past travel history, check their I-94 expiration date, and obtain proof of their electronic I-94 from their mobile device using the CBP One mobile application. The mobile application can be downloaded for free from the Apple App Store or Google Play.
CBP requires travelers to obtain an approved ESTA and apply for the I-94 by using the CBP One or the CBP I-94 website and avoid filling out the Form I-94W at a port of entry.

